# xcode include paths conflicts

Tags: c++, xcode, include-path

In MSVS when I #include <someHeader> it is searched in a different folder than the headers included with #include "someheader". Same thing should be in xcode, but it seems that it does not work. Because of this I have conflicts with local headers that have same name as std headers(String.h, etc) and I can't include std headers. I tried to change project option "Always search user paths" but it still does not work. The help message from this options says that it will solve my problem, but...

> If enabled, both #include
> <header.h>-style and #include
> "header.h"-style directives will
> search the paths in "User Header
> Search Paths" before "Header Search
> Paths", with the consequence that user
> headers (such as your own String.h
> header) would have precedence over
> system headers when using #include
> <header.h>. This is done using the
> -iquote flag for the paths provided in "User Header Search Paths". If
> disabled and your compiler fully
> supports separate user paths, user
> headers will only be accessible with
>
> ## include "header.h"-style preprocessor directives.
>
> For backwards compatibility reasons,
> this setting is enabled by default,
> but disabling it is strongly
> recommended.
> [ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS]

Do you have any idea how to  solve this? I really don't want to change my header files names or to remove search paths from project settings and use relative paths to local files (../../ ... /SomeFolder/SomeHeader.h).

Comment: The compiler command line that's used when the project is built might give someone enough detail to help with this. That should be available from some build log.

Comment: I tried to preprocess one dummy cpp file only with one include <string.h> the local header file is included :|

Comment: Command line: setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x c++ -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -mfix-and-continue -gdwarf-2 -mthumb -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -iquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing all headers extension from h to hpp... It's not a real solution, but I kept the file names and I solved the problem, for now:)